# Gestión de ramas remotas en Git con GitFlow

Tags: git, git-flow

tengo una duda en cuanto a la gestión de ramas en GIT. Estoy siguiendo GitFlow. Sé cuál es su funcionamiento en cuanto a estructura de ramas, ningún problema ahí, pero no sé como se gestiona correctamente el tema de la sincronización con remoto. me explico, por ejemplo:

- Hago una rama hotfix_problema_XXXX desde master

Si es cosa de poco y la voy a solucionar en seguida, ¿esta rama la sincronizo con remoto o no es necesario? es decir, ¿soluciono el problema y hago merge en master en local y por último borro la rama de hotfix sin pasar por remoto?

Otra duda es, ¿se deben borrar estas ramas remotas además de las locales? Es decir, las que tienen que ver con hotfix o features.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Si es algo que solo estas viendo tu, no creo que sea necesario hacer push de esa rama. Acá te dejo un enlace, donde trabajo nos basamos en ese modelo. https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Ok, gracias @joalquipe, ese es el origen de GitFlow según tengo entendido. Tenía que haber empezado por mirar ahí. Según dice, no es necesario hacer push de esa rama local. Lo que no me queda claro es si esa rama está subida a remoto (porque trabajan en ella varias personas, por ejemplo), si cuando la incorporas a la principal (bien master o develop), es conveniente borrarla o no.... osea, hacer un `git push origin :rama_a_borrar`

Comment: Como lo veo eso depende de lo que necesites, si no te hace falta eliminala sino la dejas. Ese branching model sirve como base pero al final del día lo adaptas a tus necesidades.

Comment: Ok gracias @joalquipe a ver si alguien más da su punto de vista, si no, tomaré la decisión de mantenerlas en remoto por si acaso

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he podido investigar, y por lo que me han [respondido en SO (inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801481/8496784), parece que efectivamente es una buena práctica borrar las ramas que no vayas a volver a usar, a no ser que concretamente necesites tener un histórico detallado.

En mi caso, optaré por borrarlas.